# Wrong byte is written to file

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a few bytes to a newly created file in Visual Basic.
The following code is executed:

```
compressedFileStream.WriteByte(&H00)
compressedFileStream.WriteByte(&H00)
compressedFileStream.WriteByte(&H00)
compressedFileStream.WriteByte(&H00)
compressedFileStream.WriteByte(&H00)
compressedFileStream.WriteByte(&HD5)
compressedFileStream.WriteByte(&H55)
compressedFileStream.WriteByte(&H6E)
compressedFileStream.WriteByte(&H49)
```

Unfortunately the output is not what I wrote. Using Notepad++ I see this result:

[image: Actual Result]

Creation of compressedFileStream:

```
Using compressedFileStream As FileStream = File.Create(ArchivePath & ".zip")
```

The D0 and B5 are wrong. After those two bytes that magically appeared it will continue with the correct bytes (55, 6E and 49). Did anyone actually experience this or does anyone know what can cause this?

Comment: can be issue with file encoding

Comment: How are you creating `compressedFileStream`?

Comment: I added the creation of compressedFileStream to OP

Comment: I tried your code and it works as expected.  Is there any other process that takes place after the `WriteByte` statements are executed?

Comment: Perhaps notepad++ is playing tricks on you.

Comment: Oh my god, using HxD I get the correct results. I was using the Notepad++ Hex plugin but I guess it's unstable as F! @wdosanjos if you want to I can mark your suggestion as the answer if you write an answer instead of a comment :) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works as expected.  Is there any other process that takes place after the `WriteByte` statements are executed?

Or, perhaps Notepad++ is playing tricks on you.

Comment: It indeed was Notepad++ playing tricks on me. Another hex editor shows the correct results. Thanks!